# Cargar variables dependiendo item seleccionado MVC C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Consulta

Buenas, quisiera guardar variables por defecto luego de seleccionar un item en un select(para luego insertarlas en base de datos). 
En mi caso el select "Estado de obra"(el cual se carga mediante llamada a base de datos). La idea es que dependiendo el item seleccionado, se devuelvan variables con valores para guardarlos en base de datos.

Por ejemplo,

- si selecciono 1, que devuelva las variables numero1=12 y descripcion="doce"
- si selecciono 3, que devuelva las variables numero2=13 y descripcion="trece"

De ante mano gracias

VISTA

Index

```
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Ingrese Datos</legend>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><label>Código Obra</label></td>
                <td><label>Nombre Obra</label></td>
                <td><label>Año Obra</label></td>
                <td><label>Cota</label></td>
                <td><label>Caudal Diseño</label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="txtCodObra" maxlength="10" id="txtCodObra" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="txtNomObra" maxlength="10" id="txtNomObra" /></td>
                <td><input type="number" name="txtanyoObra" min="1900" max="2050" maxlength="4" id="txtanyoObra" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="txtCota" maxlength="10" id="txtCota" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="txtCaudal" maxlength="10" id="txtCaudal" /></td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label>Estado de la Obra</label></td>
                <td><label>Cota Cámara</label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <select name="e_u" id="e_u">
                        <option value="0">Seleccione Estado</option>
                        @{
                            if (ViewData["estados"] != null)
                            {
                                IEnumerable<dynamic> estados = (IEnumerable<dynamic>)ViewData["estados"];

                                foreach (dynamic est_uso in estados)
                                {
                                    string nombreestado = est_uso.Nombreestado;
                                    int e_u = est_uso.idestado;
                                    <option value="@est_uso.idestado"> @nombreestado.ToUpper() </option>

                                }

                            }
                       //dependiendo esta seleccion, cargar variable     
                        }
                    </select>

                </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="txtCotaCam" maxlength="10" id="txtCotaCam" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Capacidad Operativa</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="txtCapOperativa" maxlength="10" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <p>
            <input id="BtnEnviar" name="Button1" type="submit" value="enviar" onclick="return validar()" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>


</form>
```

CONTROLADOR

```
    [ActionName("Index")]
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetIndex()
    {
        NameValueCollection queryString = Request.QueryString;
        IDbConnection database = new SqlConnection(config.ConnectionString);
        string query = @"
        select 
            l.cod_local 'CodigoLocalidad',
            l.nom_local 'NombreLocalidad'
        from 
                localidad l  
        ";


        IEnumerable<dynamic> estados = database.Query(query1);
        ViewData["estados"] = estados;
        return View();
    }

    [ActionName("Index")]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PostIndex(FormCollection form,  int e_u)
    {
```

//La idea es que dependiendo la selección, devuelva ciertas variables

```
        int cond = e_u;

        if (cond != 3)

        {
            string vigencia = "vigente";

        }
        else 
        {
            string vigencia = "No vigente";

        }

        string codobra = form["txtCodObra"];
        string nobra = form["txtNomObra"];
        string aobra = form["txtAnyoObra"];
        string cota = form["txtCota"];
        string cota_cam = form["txtCotaCam"];
        string caudal = form["txtCaudal"];
        string capop = form["txtCapOperativa"];


        IDbConnection database = new SqlConnection(config.ConnectionString);
        Fam201 f = new Fam201();

        f.CodObra = codobra;
        f.NomObra = nobra;
        f.AnyoObra = int.Parse(aobra);
        f.Cota = float.Parse(cota);
        f.CotaCam = float.Parse(cota_cam);
        f.Caudal = float.Parse(caudal);
        f.CapOperativa =float.Parse(capop);
        f.IdEst = e_u;


        int? id = database.Insert(f);

        string query = @"
        select 
            l.cod_local 'CodigoLocalidad',
            l.nom_local 'NombreLocalidad'
        from 
                localidad l  
        ";


        IEnumerable<dynamic> estados = database.Query(query1);
        ViewData["estados"] = estados;


        ViewData["notificacion"] = @"Registro Agregado, Codigo Obra:" + codobra + ", Nombre Obra: " + nobra + ", Año " + aobra + ".";

        return View();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

La situación está en que un elemento html option-value solo envía la propiedad value, y no el contenido/texto. Por lo que te recomiendo generes tus option-value de manera que envies los dos datos y en el método de acción lo separes:

Vista

```
<select name="e_u" id="e_u">
<option value="0">Seleccione Estado</option>
@{
    if (ViewData["estados"] != null)
    {
        IEnumerable<dynamic> estados = (IEnumerable<dynamic>)ViewData["estados"];

        foreach (dynamic est_uso in estados)
        {
            string nombreestado = est_uso.Nombreestado;
            int e_u = est_uso.idestado;
            <option value="@est_uso.idestado:@nombreestado.ToUpper()"> @nombreestado.ToUpper() </option>
        }
    }
}
</select>
```

Controllador

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string e_u)
{
    int IdEst = Convert.ToInt32(e_u.Split(':')[0]);
    string DescEst = e_u.Split(':')[1];
}
```